# How to compute accuracy?

Tags: python, neural-network

I am struggling on how to compute accuracy from my neural network. I am using the MNIST database with backpropagation algorithm. All is done from scratch.

My partial code looks like this:

```py
for x in range(1, epochs+1):
   #Compute Feedforward
   #...
   activationValueOfSoftmax = softmax(Z2)

   #Loss
   #Y are my labels
   loss = - np.sum((Y * np.log(activationValueOfSoftmax)), axis=0, keepdims=True)
   cost = np.sum(loss, axis=1) / m #m is 784

   #Backpropagation
   dZ2 = activationValueOfSoftmax - Y
   #the rest of the parameters
   #...
   #parameters update via Gradient Descent
   #...
```

Can I compute accuracy from this, or do I have to redo some parts of my NN?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have your prediction? If you want to do it step by step, create a dataframe containing y_pred and y_true, add an extra column with the condition if `y_pred == y_true` then 1, otherwise 0. Finally compute the mean score for that column and that is your accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have your 10 sized one hot y vector for your test set (10 digits), and you retrieved your hypothesis through forward prop with your training set.

```
correct = 0

    for i in range(np.shape(y)[0]):
        #argmax retrieves index of max element in hypothesis
        guess = np.argmax(hyp[i, :])
        ans= np.argmax(y[i, :])
        print("guess: ", guess, "| ans: ", ans)
        if guess == match:
            correct = correct + 1;

accuracy = (correct/np.shape(y)[0]) * 100
```

You have to do forward prop again with your weights and the TEST SET data to get your hypothesis vector (should be 10 sized) then you can loop through all the y values in the test set, using a counter variable (correct) to retrieve the amount correct. To get percentage, you just divide the correct by the number of test set examples and multiply by 100.

If you want the accuracy from the training set, just use your hypothesis (in your case activationValueOfSoftmax) and do the same.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I have found out, that my NN is basically not learning :D.